# Change option on select input by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the value on my select input by clicking on a button, but this button is on an other page.

My button is on the home page and the form with the select input is on contact page.
The select input look like this :

```
<select name="menu-vol" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required select-field w-select" id="select-vol" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="Le marmaille">Le marmaille</option>
<option value="Le Vol découverte">Le Vol découverte</option>
<option value="Le plus">Le plus</option>
<option value="L'infini">L'infini</option>
<option value="Le vol des Hauts">Le vol des Hauts</option>
<option value="Le vol de distance">Le vol de distance</option>
<option value="Le vol du Maïdo">Le vol du Maïdo</option>
</select>
```

For exemple i want when i click on the button, the input select value change to "Le Vol découverte"

I'm trying [this solution](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/standard/neanrakyr/2514494#html-tab-view) but isn't work because is not a bootstrap template i think and in this exemple the form input and the button is on the same page, not like my case.

Comment: If you need to make changes in different page and your page reloads when routing to a different page, you might want to append a `searchParam` when redirecting to the form page.  On the form page you can get the param with `(new URL(document.location)).searchParams;` and set the value there by checking the params value

Comment: Also, if you want to change when both pages are open, you should set a cookie or a session var and set a listener, maybe an observer, to check if the cookie or the session var has been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in very simple step:

In home page make your button an anchor tag like below:

```
<a href="contact.html?param=test">Goto Contact</a>
```

you can see in `href` I've passed a param with value.

Now in contact.html page, just use this below codes:

```
if (window.location.search.includes('param=test')) {
  document.getElementById('select-vol').value = 'Le Vol découverte';
}
```

Now whenever you click the anchor button in home page it redirects to contact.html page with `param=test`, and in contact.html page I'm checking condition if param=test then show the selected option which I passed as value in js code.

Answer (score 0):

Well let's assume you have a link like this:

```html
<a href="contact.html">Contact Page</a>
```

You can change the href in order to send query parameters to the target page like this:

```html
<a href="contact.html?selectedValue=Le marmaille">Contact Page</a>
```

And finally you can get the query value from URL in the Contact page and change the selected option:

```js
const selectedValue = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams.get("selectedValue");
document.getElementById("select-vol").value = selectedValue;
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).